# Configure spring kafka schema registry security

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, schema

Iam using spring kafka and avro,
The schema registry is secured with plain sasl protocol.

I must develop a kafka consumer and producer, i don't find a way with spring kafka to configure the security properties for schema registry.

Does spring kafka library already integrate this configuration ?
I need to configure kafkastore.. In a schema registry properties file?
I didn't find any examples with spring kafka

Answer (score 0):

there is docs like [this](https://fullstackcode.dev/2022/05/30/how-to-publish-subscribe-to-kafka-with-spring-boot-and-sasl-scram/) related to your question and demo examples in [github](https://github.com/ru-rocker/spring-kafka-sasl-scram).

note that with spring you can have common properties for kafka, just make sure to use spring kafka dependency, maybe first try to establish connection between both consumer and producer and then put sasl plain security.